# libtorrent inbuilt tracker

Tags: c++, http, bittorrent, tracker, libtorrent

Does libtorrent provide a inbuilt tracker? 
I was looking at the API docs and examples but could not find anything on those lines.

Other libs like BitTorando, Snark etc expose a Tracker as well.

Anyone have any idea about this or is there any code which can help me in briging up a tracker with libtorrent itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming you're talking about libtorrent-rasterbar (as in libtorrent.org); no, it does not come with a tracker.

I would recommend taking a look at [OpenTracker](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/) or [utrack](https://github.com/arvidn/utrack) (udp only).